# why can't Jsoup parse tagName "link"

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this wired senario within my Jsoup project

here is how the HTML look like:

```
<html>
..

<link> example.com </link>
..

</html>
```

when I try to use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to get the text

```
System.out.println(document.select("link").text()) ;//nothing gets printed. (it should print **example.com**)
```

but if I change the html into:

```
<html>
..

<someOtherTage> example.com </someOtherTage>
..

</html>
```

then:

```
System.out.println(document.select("someOtherTage").text()); //prints **example.com**
```

**So my question**:

Is this a bug in `Jsoup` or there is  something especial about tag name "`link`"?

**NOTE:** 
Jsoup Version used 1.6 and 1.9. Java 7 and 8

Answer (score 3):

Since the `link` element is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), JSoup has sanitized the element and moved its content into the body. (Verify this by printing the document).

To keep the content in the link element, switch to XML parsing mode:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: hanks for the info. the result is the same using `Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());` but when I print document I get <link> example.com ( closing `</link>` tag is now gone)

Comment: @nafas not the thing I'am seeing, using JSoup 1.8.3

Comment: I had the same issue with XML that had `<link>some text</link>` where the default parser did indeed push the text into the body.  This answer fixed it for me.